# numpy multiple ndarray creation at once

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create multiple matrices with numpy.zeros((N,M)). But I just realized that this not working as I though it would:

can someone explain me the outcome of the following code (1dim arrays for simplicity):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy as np

#sequential array creation 
X=np.zeros(1)
Y=np.zeros(1)
X[0],Y[0]=1.0,2.0
print X,Y

#multiple array creation
X,Y=[np.zeros(1)]*2
X[0],Y[0]=1.0,2.0
print X,Y
```

the result is

[ 1.] [ 2.]

[ 2.] [ 2.]

this means the second method to create the arrays does not work...

What is the prober way to create many ndarrays with identical dimensions in 1 line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mylist * 2
```

is equivalent to

```
mylist + mylist #resulting list has 2 references to each element in mylist 
                #stored as:
                #[mylist[0],mylist[1],...,mylist[0],mylist[1],...]
                #   ^ ----------------------^
                #   reference the same object
```

So in your case, you're making a numpy array, and then you're putting it in a list.  When you multiply that list, the resulting list has 2 references to *the same array*.

If you want to create multiple arrays and put them in a list, a list comprehension will do just fine:

```
lst_of_arrays = [ np.zeros(1) for _ in range(N) ]
```

Or if there are few enough of them to unpack, you can use a generator or a list-comprehension (below I opt for the generator):

```
X,Y = ( np.zeros(1) for _ in range(2) )
X,Y,Z = ( np.zeros(1) for _ in range(3) )
W,X,Y,Z = ( np.zeros(1) for _ in range(4) )
...
```

(and, in anticipation of an otherwise inevitable comment, in python2.x, you can use `xrange` instead of `range` to save the overhead of creating a list ...)

Comment: What's the point of saving the overhead of creating a list in code that *creates a list*?

Comment: @ecatmur, are you talking about my aside about `xrange`?  If you use `range` in python2.x, you create **2** lists (`range` creates an additional list which is iterated over in the list-comp/generator) instead of just creating 1 (the one you want).

Answer (score 3):

Another solution without using a list comprehension or generator would be:

```
X, Y = np.zeros((2,1))
```

So if you need e.g. three arrays of shape `(5, 5)` it would be:

```
X, Y, Z = np.zeros((3, 5, 5))
```

For a good explanation of what went wrong in the original example I refer to mgilson's answer.